# Can we integrate jwrapper with any continous integration tools (like jenkins, etc...)

Tags: jwrapper

Can we integrate jwrapper with any continous integration tools (like jenkins, etc...)

Could you please provide the information..

Thanks
Venkatesh M

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how exactly you want to integrate it into Jenkins but JWrapper can be used from the command line so can be integrated into build scripts etc.

http://www.jwrapper.com/getting-started.html